Best way to pass data from form to a function in Flutter?
This is the program I have running:

I have an app that is a single page.
The page's widgets are defined in separate files.
I have data that comes from the serial port and data that is entered in a form widget.
The button widget that calls the function to write the data to the file is in a separate widget from the form widget (for layout reasons and because I'm taking data from the form and the serial buffer).
I'm using Riverpod to manage the serial data.
The Serial data gets passed as a List<List> tofile write function when the button is pressed.

onPressed: () {
   if (ref.watch(serDataProvider).isNotEmpty) {
      // Write the data to a file
      writeFile(ref.watch(serDataProvider));
   }
},


The write file function is just formatting the data as a .csv file so that it comes up in Excel nicely, and in a way that I can select the data to create a chart and copy/paste readymade titles easily.
With hardcoded form data in the file write function, everything works perfectly.

I'm trying to get the form data to the function when the button is pressed.

I already have the form created and their contents go into controllers.  They work, I can print out the values locally in the form widget.

I tried creating a provider for a data class that holds it:
class Data {
  late String? temperature;
  late String? humidity;

  Data(
      this.temperature,
      this.humidity,

  factory Data.initial() {
    return Data();
  }
}

@riverpod
class FormData extends _$FormData {
  @override
  Data build() {
    return Data.initial();
  }
}

I added the data to the provider in the TextFields like this:
onChanged: (text) {
          ref.read(formDataProvider).temperature = text;
});

I added the form data to the button (function receiving FormData as the datatype) like this:
onPressed: () {
   if (ref.watch(serDataProvider).isNotEmpty) {
      // Write the data to a file
      writeFile(ref.watch(formDataProvider), ref.watch(serDataProvider));
   }
},

In the function, I wrote the the file like this:
void writeFile(Data formData, List<List<int>> listOfSamples) async {
.
. // other code
.
sink.write('Temperature: ${formData.temperature}\n');
.
. // other code
.
}

It wasn't throwing any errors, but I ended up with null (as text) in the file wherever stuff from the form was printed.
I tried passing the form data to the provider in functions a number of different ways, and got the same result.
Looking at the Riverpod page, it states:
"They are not meant to be used for local widget state, such as for:

storing form state
currently selected item
animations
generally everything that Flutter deals with a "controller" (e.g. TextEditingController)"

So, it appears that my approach is maybe not a good one.  If that is the case, what are some good ways of getting the form data to my function?

So, apparently my provider was being disposed of.  Not sure why, I tried all combinations of ref.read and ref.watch and it didn't make a difference.  Ended up having to change @riverpod to @Riverpod(keepAlive: true), then my provider stopped getting reset.
I'm finding Riverpod a little annoying.  I come up with a data structure, implement it as a class with some methods, and get it working well.  Then when I try an turn it into a provider, half the stuff either won't compile or is broken, and to fix it you have to do some weird and non-intuitive.
